# How can you add tooltip to an anchor

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an anchor which looks like

```
<a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable">
  <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">3:42pm</span> <span class="fc-title">Abc</span></div>
</a>
```

and I want to add

```
data-toggle="tooltip"
```

and tittle is come from `<span>` value like  `<span class="fc-title">Abc</span>`
How to do this?

Comment: Do it with JavaScript instead. See [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#tooltipoptions).

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your tooltips with a `title` option. There you can pass in a function to get the content you want to show.

```js
$('a').tooltip({
  title: e => $('.fc-title', e).text()
});
```

```css
a {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pjaaA8dDz/5BgdFUPX6M/9SUZv4d12SUPF0axWc+VRZkx5xU3daN+lYb49+Ax+Tl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<br /><br />

<a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable" data-toggle="tooltip">
  <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">3:42pm</span> <span class="fc-title">Abc</span></div>
</a>
```

You can read about the [options in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#options).

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="I am anchor">I am anchor</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Answer (score -3):

just put data-toogle in the span

```
<a href="#"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="I love you">Try</span> Me</a>
```

and initiate it with

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Comment: what is this  "I love you" ?